# jQuery callback function pass event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event as follow which works fine:

```
$('#showmenu').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    show_menu();
    return false;
});
```

where show_menu is:

```
function show_menu(e) {
    if (!collapseForm.is(':visible')) {
        collapseForm.show();
        showMenu.removeClass(chevronDown).addClass(checvronUp);
        searchAgain.hide();
    } else {
        collapseForm.hide();
        showMenu.removeClass(checvronUp).addClass(checvronDown);
        searchAgain.show();
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like that:

```
$('#showmenu').off('click').on('click', show_menu(e));
```

Is it possible to pass "e" to the callback function by doing the following?

```
function show_menu(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!collapseForm.is(':visible')) {
        collapseForm.show();
        showMenu.removeClass(chevronDown).addClass(checvronUp);
        searchAgain.hide();
    } else {
        collapseForm.hide();
        showMenu.removeClass(checvronUp).addClass(chevronDown);
        searchAgain.show();
    }
    return false;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The event object is passed to the function when the function is called (by the event firing).

You have to pass the *function* to the `on` method.

```
$('#showmenu').off('click').on('click', show_menu);
```

Comment: I am getting: Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined, see updated question

Comment: @Alex — I'm not getting that: http://jsbin.com/subecom/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: see screenshot attached

Comment: @Alex — In the question you wrote `function show_menu(e) {
    e.preventDefault();`. That isn't what the screenshot shows.